# Position a div on top of a sliding Jquery div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to position a child div of #handle, on top of #handle, which is a div that slides up and down. Here's what I'm working with right now:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".resizable").resizable({
    handles: {
      'n': '#handle'
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  background: #555;
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
  position: fixed !important;
  top: auto !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#handle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  top: -29px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="resizable">
  <div id="handle" class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

I can't figure out how the positioning would work, while still being able to slide the drawer up and down. Is this something I can accomplish with positioning properties or z-index? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### For the first question:

For the `#container` element, modify the `height` rule to:

```
height: calc(100% - 30px);
```

The `calc()` function is supported in [most browers](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc).

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".resizable").resizable({
    handles: {
      'n': '#handle'
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  background: #555;
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
  position: fixed !important;
  top: auto !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#handle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  top: -29px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="resizable">
  <div id="handle" class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

#### For the second question

The problem is that `.ui-resizable-handle` has a `font-size` property that is set to `0.1px`. You only need to add a rule:

```
#handle div {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".resizable").resizable({
    handles: {
      'n': '#handle'
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  background: #555;
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
  position: fixed !important;
  top: auto !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#handle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  top: -29px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

#handle div {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="resizable">
  <div id="handle" class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n">
      <div>content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I honestly had no idea that function existed. Thanks! Any idea how I'd lay a child of #handle on top?

Comment: Ah, you want that is child is on the movable bar or on the top of the container?

Comment: Yessir, I'll modify the question to make a bit more sense.

Comment: Modified my answer.

Comment: You're awesome. Thanks!